# Why is the deployment of Azure function to api management failing?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, deployment, azure-functions, azure-api-management

Using Visual Studio 17.8.3, I'm trying to publish a .Net8 isolated C# Azure Function project to Azure, including loading it to an API Management service, with a Github CI/CD workflow. This is one of the options on the publish menu.

The build stage works after changing:

```
DOTNET_CORE_VERSION_INPROC: 6.0.x
```

to

```
DOTNET_CORE_VERSION_INPROC: 8.0.x
```

but the deploy stage fails with the following message:

"Login failed with Error: Using auth-type: SERVICE_PRINCIPAL. Not all values are present. Ensure 'client-id' and 'tenant-id' are supplied.. Make sure 'az' is installed on the runner. If 'enable-AzPSSession' is true, make sure 'pwsh' is installed on the runner together with Azure PowerShell module. Double check if the 'auth-type' is correct."

It seems there are steps that need to be taken before the Visual Studio generated workflow can work.

Am I missing anything? Is there a detailed tutorial for this?

My Workflow:

```
name: Build and deploy .NET Core application to Function App NewKimaAPI with API Management Service KimaAPI-NewKimaAPI
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: NewKimaAPI
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: NewKimaAPI
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 8.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: NewKimaAPI
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION_INPROC: 8.0.x
  AZURE_APIM_RESOURCEGROUP: HeritageBrowserIL
  AZURE_APIM_SERVICENAME: KimaAPI
  AZURE_APIM_API_ID: NewKimaAPI
  AZURE_APIM_RESOURCE_PATH: /
  AZURE_APIM_SWAGGERURL: ''
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Setup .NET Core (for inproc extensions)
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION_INPROC }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: functionapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Deploy to Azure Function App
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.NewKimaAPI_AABB }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.KimaAPI_SPN }}
    - name: Import API into Azure API Management
      run: az apim api import --path "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_RESOURCE_PATH }}" --resource-group ${{ env.AZURE_APIM_RESOURCEGROUP }} --service-name ${{ env.AZURE_APIM_SERVICENAME }} --api-id ${{ env.AZURE_APIM_API_ID }} --specification-url "${{ env.AZURE_APIM_SWAGGERURL }}" --specification-format OpenApi --subscription-required false
```

Comment: Please provide your GITHUB workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below given alternative to achieve your requirement.

- Deploy the function to Azure function app using GitHub actions.
- Configure APIM in the Function App manually in Portal.

**My GitHub workflow to deploy the function to Azure:**

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
  
#set environment variables

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'
  DOTNET_VERSION: '8.0.x' 

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
          popd
      - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: fa
        with:
          app-name: '<functionapp_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_C5XXXXX1019 }}
```

**Deployment status in GitHub:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Navigate to `Function App=>API Management=>Create New APIM and API or select existing ones`.

- Created New APIM and linked it to function app.

[image]

- Click on `Go to API management`=>go to APIs=>Create a new API=>Select Function App and provide function app's details.

[image]

**Existing APIM:**

[image]

**Testing the imported function:**

[image]

**References:**

[Import an Azure Function App as an API in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api).